# messed up nightwatch output in jenkins

Tags: windows, jenkins, nightwatch.js

when I try running the nightwatch tests in Jenkins on a Windows slave, I get output that screwed:

```
 âˆš Element <.test-fb-btn> was visible after 343 milliseconds.
 âˆš Element <body> was visible after 221 milliseconds.
 âˆš Element <.fouc> was not present after 372 milliseconds.
 âˆš Page was loaded after 71 milliseconds.
 âˆš Element
```

Any way to fix this?